# Node.js middleware authentication with variable

Tags: node.js, express, routes, middleware

before I route and render a website I want to check if the user is authenticated and of a certain type. The "middleware" looks like this:

```
function isAuthenticated(req,res,next,required_type){
if(Parse.User.current()){
    Parse.User.current().fetch().then(function(fetchedUser){
        var type = fetchedUser.get("type");            
        if(type == required_type){
            return next();
        }else{
            res.redirect("/login");
        }

    }, function(error){
        res.redirect("/login");
    });
}else{
    res.redirect("/login");
}
}
```

This part seems fair and easy enough. Here is how I try to use the middleware before I route:

```
app.get('/dashboard_client',isAuthenticated, dashboard_client_view_controller.displayView);
```

My questions is, how do I set the required_type variable, since Node.js somehow know how to get and find the req,res and next variables. Thank you for answering such an stupidly and I guess obvious to solve question.

Comment: `app.get('/dashboard_client/:requiredtype',isAuthenticated, dashboard_client_view_controller.displayView);`  Then call GET /dashboard_client/requiredtype where requiredtype is your type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this approach:

//middleware:

```
function isAuthenticated(required_type) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        if (Parse.User.current()) {
            Parse.User.current().fetch().then(function (fetchedUser) {
                var type = fetchedUser.get("type");
                if (type == required_type) {
                    return next();
                } else {
                    res.redirect("/login");
                }

            }, function (error) {
                res.redirect("/login");
            });
        } else {
            res.redirect("/login");
        }
    }

};
```

//route

```
app.get('/dashboard_client',isAuthenticated('admin'), dashboard_client_view_controller.displayView);
```